# HP ILO utility for Ubuntu - hponcfg fails due to missing hp-ilo package

Tags: ubuntu, hp, hp-proliant, ilo

I'm working with an *Ubuntu*-based system running on an [HP ProLiant DL360p Gen8](https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docId=emr_na-c03223744) server. I prefer to install HP's management agents when I can for full hardware monitoring/configuration capabilities.

Per HP's documentation, I added the download tree for the [Ubuntu Management Component Pack](https://downloads.linux.hpe.com/SDR/downloads/MCP/Ubuntu/) to: `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Following an `apt-get update`, I was able to run:

```
apt-get install cpqacuxe hp-ams hp-health hp-snmp-agents hpacucli hponcfg
```

So I run the `hponcfg -w ilo.xml` to retrieve ILO settings, with result:

```
root@zetavault1:~# hponcfg 
HP Lights-Out Online Configuration utility
Version 4.2.0 Date 6/10/2013 (c) Hewlett-Packard Company, 2013
ERROR:  Could not find the Management Processor Device Node.
        Please check if the iLO driver module is installed and running properly.
        ACTION REQUIRED: Install/Re-install hp Lights-Out driver package('hp-ilo' RPM) for iLO.
```

The takeaway is that the ILO device isn't initialized or available to the OS due to the missing `hp-ilo` package. My system's info is:

```
# uname -a && cat /etc/issue
Linux zetavault1 3.10.28-42-zetavault #1 SMP Mon Jan 27 09:33:22 GMT 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS \n \l
```

- Are there any workarounds for this?
- For people who run Ubuntu on HP gear, are there other things I should be watching out for?
- Does HP not fully support Ubuntu as an OS target?

Comment: You're not running an Ubuntu kernel. HP's kernel module probably isn't available for that particular kernel version. In which case you get to yell at Zetavault or whoever built the thing.

Comment: @MichaelHampton On RHEL, the hp-ilo package isn't tied to kernel version.

Comment: It was my understanding that HP still only officially supported RHEL/SUSE at least the last time I downloaded the SPP, has this changed since September?

Comment: @ewwhite On RHEL 6, sure. On RHEL 7, the module is now in the kernel itself, so there's no need to package it separately.

Comment: @davidv Operating systems like Ubuntu and CentOS have the Management Component Pack (MCP) instead of the HP SPP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hp-ilo package doesn't need to exist anymore on modern Linux systems, since the driver is now part of the mainline kernel (since 2.6.33 or thereabouts).

It should not be necessary to do anything with a standard kernel on any mainstream Linux distribution, since they all build the `hpilo` module and make it available by default.

However, you seem to have a nonstandard kernel from a third party. In this case, you may have to manually load the module:

```
modprobe hpilo
```

Or, you may find that the people who built the kernel (Zetavault?) did not actually build in this module. In this case you need to take up the issue with them.

Comment: D'oh... I'll pursue it with the vendor.

Answer (score 0):

If someone still arrives to this question, `ipmitool` works fine on HP servers as well.

After installing the tool, get the list of users:

```
$ ipmitool user list 1
ID  Name       Callin  Link  Auth   IPMI Msg  Channel Priv     Limit
1               true   false        false             NO ACCESS
2   root        true   true         true              ADMINISTRATOR
etc...
```

Change *root* password (ID = 2 in this case):

```
$  ipmitool user set password 2
```

It will be prompted to enter a new password.